# Is list component good for chat displaying Chat data

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile

i want to create a chat app using flex 4.5 mobile project for android device. For the chat screen, i wanted it to look glossy and stylish. Hence i thought i would use the list component and disable the selection in it. I m able to add the chat messages into the list. But i doubt if large chat data might hinder the performance. Im using a collection and i ve binded it with the list. Whenever i receive a chat i update the collection and it gets displayed in the list. Can someone tell me if his could pose a performance problem as list component is not intended for this purpose.

Thanks..

Comment: If you don't need List functionality (selecting items etc.), just use DataGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't a list be intended for this purpose? I'd say a List is the exact component to use for this kind of task. I don't see any performance issues unless you're doing something wrong with the eventListeners or your ItemRenderer. For best performance, use an AS only renderer.

However, as memory is always a concern on mobile devices, you might wanna consider limiting the amount of items in the list, say 100 or so. You likely won't get back to the beginning of the list (your conversation) anyway.